# How to change buffer size from degrees to distance by meters in PostGIS?

Tags: postgresql, buffer, postgis, points

```
SELECT ST_Buffer(geom, 400)
FROM my_table;
```

This query creates a buffer in 400 degrees. How can I change it to have  400m buffers around points?
I have tried to use `ST_Transform` and `ST_SetSRID` but I got errors. Most likely because I structure my query wrong.
Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ST_buffer` uses the projection unit. You can cast the `geometry` to a `geography` to use meters, or rely on a suitable local projection whose unit is in meters.

```
SELECT ST_Buffer(geom::geography, 400)
FROM my_table;
```

If it is not yet set, you may have to set the original CRS first

```
SELECT ST_Buffer(st_setSRID(geom,4326)::geography, 400)
FROM my_table;
```

Comment: Thank you very much it works. My mistake was that I was missing `::geography` part.